# error with Python progromm many values to unpack

Tags: python

```
def main(data):
    data = data.replace("\n", " ")
    data = data.lstrip("{ <% list")
    data = data.strip(' %>}').strip().strip(';')
    data = data.split(" <% list")
    dictionary = {}
    for line in data:
        values, key = line.split("=:")
        values = values.strip()
        values = values.lstrip("(")
        values = values.rstrip(")")
        values = values.split(";")
        values = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), values))
        key = key.strip()
        dictionary[key] = values
    return dictionary
print(main("{ <% list(cema_56; ator_218 ; lara_164 ; ator_370 )=: arenar; %> <% list( reer ;ina ; lebebi_345 ) =: usis_936; %> <% list(atan_207 ; enen)=: gelain_16; %><% list(ceonri_770; atso_148 ; eredre_533 )=: lace; %>}"))
```

```
 ----> 8         values, key = line.split("=:")
      9         values = values.strip()
     10         values = values.lstrip("(")

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Do you know what the line looks like?  Is it possible that the line doesn't contain `=:` or contains two of them?  Did you mean `:=`, which is more common?

Comment: Please provide examples of what `line` contains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging it?

```
print(line)
print(line.split("=:"))
values, key = line.split("=:")
```

You'll find that not every line contains exactly one `=:` and so `line.split` does not have exactly two results as your code requires.

You could add:

```
for line in data:
  parts = line.split("=:")
  if len(parts)!=2: continue
  values, key = parts
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split),

str.split() returns a list, and you are trying to unpack that list using two parameters, it will work when the list has two elements, but won't when the list is smaller or bigger.

For example

```
x, y = [1] # wont work
x, y = [1, 2, 3] # wont work
```

Answer (score 0):

```
values, key = line.split("=:")
```

It's fairly clear from the error that `line.split("=:")` is splitting into a list with more than two items, and thus the unpack is failing. You can, however, force `str.split` to only split *once*.

```
values, key = line.split("=:", 1)
```